# JMeter Groovy convert JSON response to string

Tags: json, groovy, jmeter

I've been looking through various solutions for converting JSON responses to string, but I'm still getting something wrong.

I'm trying to read the response from a post request, convert it to a string and modify it (using groovy), then pass it on the next request. The problem seems to be in the groovy script, it's not reading in the response from the first HTTP request and I'm not sure how to fix that.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: There's no property called `Token` in your json... so `response.Token` will be null

Comment: Thanks, it's working now. "token" was in the response (forgot to add it in the screenshot), so I just needed to change "response.Token..." to "response.token...".

Comment: maybe delete this question as it was just a typo?  Glad you got it working :-D